# Orbeon Form Builder- Loading data from Orbeon Tables to Custom tables

Tags: mysql, orbeon

I want a code sample to load data from the `orbeon_form_data` table to a custom table that I have created in MySQL. I can see that data is getting saved in MySQL in `orbeon_form_data`, but I want all the fields values to be saved in a new table I've created. Can I have a sample MySQL trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer

```
 DELIMITER $$
    create trigger <triggername> before insert 
    on orbeon_form_data 
    for each row begin
        if new.app = '<appname>' and new.form = '<formname>' then
            delete from <tablename> where document_id = new.document_id;
            if new.deleted = 'N' then
                insert into <tablename> set document_id = new.document_id,
                    <columnName1> = extractValue(new.xml, '/form/mySection/txtTitle'),
                    <columnName2> = extractValue(new.xml, '/form/mySection/drpAgreementType'),
                    <columnName3> = extractValue(new.xml, '/form/mySection/txtFullName');
            end if;
        end if;
    end;$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Here the tablename is the custom table that we have created in MySQL and columnName1,2,3 refers it's columns that is mapped from Orbeon Form Controls.